# How to call AJAX function from a popup appeared using "Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox plugin"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm using PHP,Smarty, jQuery, Colorbox jQuery plugin, etc. for my website. All the necessary files required have been included in index.tpl file, so I've not mentioned those files here. They are getting included and working fine. 
From one smarty template file I'm calling the Colorbox popup. The code for it is as follows:

```
<a href="{$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=user_transaction_detail&page={$cur_page}&txn_no={$my_transaction.transaction_no}&user_id={$my_transaction.transaction_user_id}&from_date={$from_date}&to_date={$to_date}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}#searchPopContent" class="c-icn c-edit-n inline_edit_transaction_details">edit</a>

{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".inline_edit_transaction_details").colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'),width:999, height:999});
}); 

</script> 
{/literal}
```

The lightbox is also getting displayed properly. For your reference I'm attaching the screenshot here.
[image]
Now I want to call a jQuery AJAX function upon clicking on Update link as shown in the attached image. For testing purpose I put an alert message at the beginning of AJAX function but not able to call it. For your reference I'm putting the code from smarty template below.
The code from the Colorbox popup(Smarty template) is as follows:

```
<td><a class="edit_user_transaction_status" href="{$control_url}{$query_path}?op=edit_user_transaction&page={$page}&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&transaction_data_assign={$user_transaction_details.transaction_data_assign}&user_id={$user_id}{if $user_name!=''}&user_name={$user_name}{/if}{if $user_email_id!=''}&user_email_id={$user_email_id}{/if}{if $user_group!=''}&user_group={$user_group}&{/if}{if $user_sub_group!=''}&user_sub_group={$user_sub_group}{/if}{if $from_date!=''}&from_date={$from_date}{/if}{if $to_date!=''}&to_date={$to_date}{/if}{if $transaction_status!=''}&transaction_status={$transaction_status}{/if}{if $transaction_no!=''}&transaction_no={$transaction_no}{/if}">Update</a></td>
```

The jQuery AJAX function is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//This function is use for edit transaction status
    $(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function() {  alert("Hello");

      $(".edit_user_transaction_status").bind('click', function(){
        $.colorbox.close();
      });

         e.preventDefault();
         //for confirmation that status change
         var ans=confirm("Are you sure to change status?");
         if(!ans) {
             return false;
         }  
         var post_url           = $(this).attr('href');
         var transaction_status_update = $('#transaction_status_update').val();      

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: post_url+"&transaction_status_update="+transaction_status_update,
                 data:$('#transaction_form').serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',  
             success: function(data) {              
                 var error = data.login_error;

                 $(".ui-widget-content").dialog("close");
                //This variables use for display title and success massage of transaction update              
                 var dialog_title   = data.title;              
                 var dialog_message = data.success_massage; 
                 //This get link where want to rerdirect
                 var redirect_link  = data.href;            

                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+dialog_message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,
                     height: 80,
                     close: function(){                                     
                         document.location.href =redirect_link;
                     }                  
                 });                    

                 $dialog.dialog('open');                    
             }          
        });
     });
});
```

I tried a lot to make a call to this function but couldn't give a call. It's also not giving any errors when I checked in console of firebug. So I think no syntactic errors are there. Can anyone help me in calling this function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".edit_user_transaction_status").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // apply in click event not outside
     alert("Hello");
});
```

or

```
      $(".edit_user_transaction_status").bind('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();  // apply in click event not outside
        $.colorbox.close();
      });
```

reference [e.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)